# st_transform producing spurious ribbons across region

Tags: r, sf

I am trying to use st_transform on PERZONES shapefile available here . In its native projection, it looks like this:
[image]

However, when I run the command:

```
tansformedPF<-st_transform(PF,"+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs") 
##This should be the MODIS sinusoidal projection
```

I get:
[image]

I thought maybe `st_transform_proj` would fix the problem but it did not. I also tried to plot the transformed file in Earth Engine just in case it was a problem with R's plotting and not the raster itself, but EE also shows the bands. I've used st_transform with the same destination crs with other shapefiles with no problem.

I also tried `st_wrap_dateline(PF, options = c("WRAPDATELINE=YES")` and `st_wrap_dateline(PF, options = c("WRAPDATELINE=YES", "DATELINEOFFSET=180")`  before passing to `st_transform`, but no luck.   The native proj4string is "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=71 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs".

Any workarounds to reproject this file without the bands?  I am open to another reproject function, but st_transform seems to be the one to use.

Comment: Sorry, the link to the shapefile is here: https://doi.pangaea.de/10.1594/PANGAEA.888600?format=html#download

Comment: that is just some of your polygons going "behind" the map, clip to the valid region of your new projection

Comment: @Ian Turton if I understand you correctly, I should just clip to the land regions ("valid region"?).  However, that doesn't solve the problem of the bands across Russia.

Comment: Any polygon that crosses a "tear" (discontinuity) in a reprojection needs to be split into multiple polygons precisely along the tear line. (sorry no time for full answer at this point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Spacedman

Alternatively, this also works:

```
PF %>% 
  st_transform(4326) %>% 
  st_wrap_dateline() %>% 
  st_transform("+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs") -> 
  s2
```

According to edzer [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1046), "The issue arises if the antimeridian is used to split the Earth for projection, as does sinusoidal and also equidistant rectilinear (used by sf for plotting geographic, longlat coordinates). "

Answer (score 5):

Here's the full solution. To split polygons, use `st_difference` with a very thin buffer - this also makes sure you don't get any edge effects at the tear line.

I'm going to work with a subset of the biggest polygons to save time. Read the data in and choose the big ones:

```
> perm_full = st_read("./UiO_PEX_PERZONES_5.0_20181128_2000_2016_NH.shp")
> pa = perm_full[st_area(perm_full) > max(st_area(perm_full))/4,]
```

Next construct a line from the pole up to somewhere near the equator at the top of the projected map. This will be our tear line when we reproject. Make a ten metre wide buffer polygon:

```
> am = st_linestring(x=rbind(c(0,0),c(0,4000000)))
> amb = st_buffer(am, dist=10)
```

Now split. When plotted you can see a line which is actually a 10 metre gap sliced through that chunk of what I think is Russia. My apologies to Vladimir Putin.

```
> pasplit = st_difference(pa$geometry, st_sfc(amb,crs=st_crs(pa)))
> plot(pasplit)
```

[image]

Now reproject using your modis projection...

```
> modis = "+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs"
> plot(st_transform(pasplit, modis))
```

[image]

tested on the full dataset:

[image]